# cakephp 2.5 Router - part of language string in URL

Tags: cakephp, router, cakephp-2.5

CakePHP Version 2.5.2
Config.Language 'spa'

If i'm in
    `mydomain.com/backoffice`
and i reload (ctrl-r) i get again
    `mydomain.com/backoffice`

If i call in UsersController in action deleteCache at the end:
    `return $this->redirect('/backoffice');`
i get
    `mydomain.com/users/sbackoffice`
Please note the "s" before backoffice. That seems to be a part of the config.language

If i set the Config.language to 'eng' i get
`mydomain.com/users/ebackoffice`
Please note now the 'e' before backoffice.

My routes.php:

```
    Router::connect('/backoffice', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'backoffice'));

  Router::connect('/:language/:controller/:action/*',
        array(),
        array('language' => 'eng|spa')
    );

    Router::connect('/:language/:controller',
        array('action' => 'index'),
        array('language' => 'eng|spa')
    );

    Router::connect('/:language', array('controller' => 'technologies', 'action' => 'home'),
        array('language' => 'eng|spa')
    );
```

Any idea?
How can i debug this?

Comment: You maybe try ``return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'backoffice'));``

Comment: That brings me to `/eng/users/backoffice`. The problem is, that there are  a lot of redirects in the code like `return $this->redirect('/backoffice');` and i want to resolve it from routes.php without changing all the redirects. And i'd like to find the reason for the "one letter" of the language code.

Comment: You will have to change these redirects. It is your fault that you didn't do it right the first time. *All* site internal links should use the array notation for exactly the reason you encounter now. The router can't magically know that this string needs to be prefixed with the language.

Comment: OK, thanks, now i understand - i'll change all to array notation. that works. Thank you Salines and burzum